# MongoDB Internet connection failure

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

I have MongoDB set up and running on Ubuntu 12.04LTS server. Everything works fine on localhost and from computers inside the local network using macs and linux boxes. However, when I try to connect thru the Internet such as:
mongo --host 
I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: mydomain.com:27017/test
Thu Jul 11 13:22:09.102 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server  mydomain.com:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114
exception: connect failed
```

However, if I connect as:

```
mongo --host mydomain.com --nodb
```

I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
```

> 

but I then cannot connect to any dbs

My mongodb.conf file reads:

```
dbpath=/data/db

#where to log
logpath=/data/mongo/mongodb.log

logappend=true
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
auth = false here
```

iptables contain:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:28017
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017
```

I can connect to the mongodb web monitor OK

The /data/db permissions are set to 777

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to specify bind_ip? I believe MongoDB binds on all IPs by default. In fact, I know specifying 0.0.0.0 used to make it bind to the hostname (not sure if it still does)

Comment: Ive had it both ways with no difference

Comment: Just to rule out any other problems, can you connect to the server externally through another means. Say, SSH or even just ping?

Comment: Also, maybe trying doing netstat -a on the mongo server.

Comment: most likely your server is behind a NAT and not on the actual direct internet or it has more than one ip address where one is accessible outside your local network. you might want to find out if that is the case and then bind to the right ip when you start mongod. If you are behind a firewall you will need to configure the firewall to forward the port to the right server. ONE THING. ITS NEVER NEVER NEVER good to open your db server to the internet EVER.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the EC2 server, it is likely that you need to configure the security policy in EC2 console, where you can enable the public port access.

Comment: In that case, would you please use ps command to check if the mongod process has been started.

Comment: yep mongod is running I can connect just fine on the server or from a computer on the LAN